# API response data not getting saved in JSON locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am running a script to fetch data from a public endpoint url- https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json which is returning data of pools in 2 arrays- official and unofficial. I only need unofficial array data and trying to save it locally. The terminal shows API response with some 85k data points fetched but the script is not saving data in JSON.

Seems basic, but any help would be good!

Here's the script:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const API_URL = 'https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json';
const JSON_FILE_PATH = 'data/allPools.json';
console.log("Script is starting...");

async function fetchAndSavePools() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
        console.log("Fetched data from API.");
    if (!response.data || !response.data.unofficial || !Array.isArray(response.data.unofficial)) {
        console.log("API response does not contain 'unofficial' array or is not structured as expected.");
        console.log("API Response:", response.data);
        return;
    }

    const currentPools = response.data.unofficial;

    // Check if the JSON file already exists
    let allPoolsData = [];

    if (fs.existsSync(JSON_FILE_PATH)) {
        // Read the existing data from the file
        const existingData = fs.readFileSync(JSON_FILE_PATH, 'utf-8');
        allPoolsData = JSON.parse(existingData);
    }

    // Append the new pools data to the existing data
    allPoolsData.push(...currentPools);

    // Save all pools data to the JSON file
    fs.writeFileSync(JSON_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(allPoolsData, null, 2));

    console.log(`All pools data saved to '${JSON_FILE_PATH}'.`);
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching and saving pools:", error);
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like it should work, but you could use the callbacks in the sync function to see if any errors occurred and which? Also, you might want to look into `fs/promises` so you can make that work nicely with `await` and `catch` to see if there any errors.

Comment: Set aside the entire contents of the function and write a literal string to the file. What happens?